# Using Android Fingerprint API to check if a new fingerprint has been added

Tags: android, security, android-fingerprint-api

I am doing some testing of an application that uses android fingerprint authentication. This app only allows fingerprint authentication, but it is possible to add a new fingerprint using the lock screen pattern, and authenticate with the app using the new fingerprint. I notice that the google play store requires password reentry when a new fingerprint has been added.

My question is: How can I make use of the Fingerprint API to check to see if a new fingerprint has been added to implement this same behavior in my own application?